# Is it a way to prevent gtest (C++) from catching exceptions and segmentation faults?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Looks like Google Test (gtest) framework for C++ somehow catches all failed assertions, exceptions and segmentation faults. The test is marked as failed but the test suite itself recovers and runs the tests that follow after.

This looks kind of cool, just that the diagnostic output that the gtest framework prints to console is very limited. CLion IDE would provide much more information, including the full stack trace and variables. Is it an easy way to turn the gtest "crash recovery" mechanism off?

Comment: I think it is the correct behavior. If you have a problem, then you run the test under a debugger. Some tests frameworks allows to specify expected exception.

Comment: It is exactly that I am doing, running the test under debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite sure that GTest cannot "catch" segmentation fault - it's OS interrupting your program, not program interrupting itself.

To disable catching failures, you can do the following (from [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.10.0/googletest/docs/advanced.md#controlling-how-failures-are-reported))

- Disable catching exceptions
  Set environment variable `GTEST_CATCH_EXCEPTIONS` to zero or run your tests with `--gtest_catch_exceptions=0` flag
- Make GTest put a breakpoint on failure (when running under debugger) 
  Set environment variable `GTEST_BREAK_ON_FAILURE` to non-zero value or run your tests with `--gtest_break_on_failure` flag

The second option will drop you directly into debugger interactive mode on any failure, not only escaped exception.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this for a specific test case only?

Comment: @Dologan I don't think there is. You would have to run test binary once with filter on the test you want to use these features and then second time with negative filter to run everything but this test.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your test binary with the option `--gtest_catch_exceptions=0`. This will cause the test to crash on exception

> Do not report exceptions as test failures. Instead, allow them
> to crash the program or throw a pop-up (on Windows).

Alternatively you can set this environmental var `GTEST_CATCH_EXCEPTIONS` to 0;

These features are mentioned in [gtest docs](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#disabling-catching-test-thrown-exceptions)

Comment: Broken link, FYI